# Loss Function & Its Inputs For Binary Classification PyTorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to write a neural Network for binary classification in PyTorch and I'm confused about the loss function.

I see that BCELoss is a common function specifically geared for binary classification. I also see that an output layer of N outputs for N possible classes is standard for general classification. However, for binary classification it seems like it could be either 1 or 2 outputs.

So, should I have 2 outputs (1 for each label) and then convert my 0/1 training labels into [1,0] and [0,1] arrays, or use something like a sigmoid for a single-variable output?

Here are the relevant snippets of code so you can see:

```
self.outputs = nn.Linear(NETWORK_WIDTH, 2) # 1 or 2 dimensions?


def forward(self, x):
  # other layers omitted
  x = self.outputs(x)           
  return F.log_softmax(x)  # <<< softmax over multiple vars, sigmoid over one, or other?

criterion = nn.BCELoss() # <<< Is this the right function?

net_out = net(data)
loss = criterion(net_out, target) # <<< Should target be an integer label or 1-hot vector?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 74):

For binary outputs you can use ***1*** output unit, so then:

```
self.outputs = nn.Linear(NETWORK_WIDTH, 1)
```

Then you use [`sigmoid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.sigmoid) activation to map the values of your output unit to a range between ***0*** and ***1*** *(of course you need to arrange your training data this way too)*:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    # other layers omitted
    x = self.outputs(x)           
    return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

Finally you can use the [`torch.nn.BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss):

```py
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

net_out = net(data)
loss = criterion(net_out, target)
```

This should work fine for you.

You can also use [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss), this loss function already includes the `sigmoid` function so you could leave it out in your forward.

If you, want to use ***2*** output units, this is also possible. But then you need to use [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) instead of `BCELoss`. The `Softmax` activation is already included in this loss function.

---

*Edit: I just want to emphasize that there is a **real** difference in doing so. Using **2** output units gives you twice as many weights compared to using **1** output unit.. So these two alternatives are not equivalent.*

Comment: Thanks for great answer!
The last question about 1 and 2 output units. When would I want to use one over another?

Comment: @никта Good question, actually I'm not sure if there is a preferred strategy when using these two. I think it is more a matter of taste. The main difference here is not the number of units but the loss function aka activation function *softmax* vs *sigmoid*. So you could check for the activation functions which suit your problem better. But in most cases you're probably not noticing a major difference in the capability of the resulting network. As this is a minor change I suggest to test both and check which works best for your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

*Some theoretical add up:*

For binary classification (say class 0 & class 1), the network should have only 1 output unit. Its output will be 1 (for class 1 present or class 0 absent) and 0 (for class 1 absent or class 0 present).

For loss calculation, you should first pass it through sigmoid and then through BinaryCrossEntropy (BCE). Sigmoid transforms the output of the network to probability (between 0 and 1) and BCE then maximizes the likelihood of the desired output.